# Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are measurable, then $\lambda(A)+\lambda(B)=\lambda(A \cup B)+\lambda(A \cap B)$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are measurable,  then $\lambda(A)+\lambda(B)=\lambda(A \cup B)+\lambda(A \cap B)$**

I tried to prove it using

$A\cup B =(A\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap B)\cup(A^c\cap B)$

but failed. Give me other hints. Thank you!

Comment: $A \setminus (A \cap B)$ and $B \setminus (A \cap B)$ are disjoint sets, and both are disjoint from $A \cap B$. Use additivity to conclude.

Comment: Also, you may use $A= (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$ and $B= (A\cap B)\cup (A^c \cap B)$. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. The equality you mention results in: $$\lambda(A\cup B)=\lambda(A\cap B^c)+\lambda(A\cap B)+\lambda(A^c\cap B)$$
because we are dealing with a union of disjoint sets. Adding up $\lambda(A\cap B)$ on both sides gives: $$\lambda(A\cup B)+\lambda(A\cap B)=\lambda(A\cap B^c)+2\lambda(A\cap B)+\lambda(A^c\cap B)$$
Now apply the equalities $\lambda(A)=\lambda(A\cap B)+\lambda(A\cap B^c)$ and $\lambda(B)=\lambda(A\cap B)+\lambda(A^c\cap B)$ on RHS and you are ready.

Comment: It really helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to determine $\lambda(A\cup B)$. The property of the measure which can help you here is the $\sigma-$additivity. But in order to use it we must have disjoint sets in the argument of $\lambda$.

We can write: $A\cup B=A\(A\cap B)\cup B\(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B)$. The RHS is an union of disjoint sets. (Make a sketch!).

Then $\lambda(A\cup B)=\lambda(A)+\lambda(B)-2\lambda(A\cap B)+\lambda(A\cap B)$.

Rearranging yields the desired result.

Comment: This answer is only valid under the extra condition: $\lambda(A\cap B)\neq\infty$. If that is not satisfied then the RHS of the equality has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:use the definition of mesurability to find two equations